# GroupMemberCountExceedsAllowedLimit error while adding a AAD SG on powerbi workspace

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, powerbi-embedded

I have been trying to add one AAD "Security" Group as a "viewer" to my Power BI workspace linked to "Embedded Capacity (A1)" but its keep on failing with below error i.e. **GroupMemberCountExceedsAllowedLimit**, As per error message looks its due to limit on total number of members in SG but I've even tried removing all users from SG (empty SG) but the error still persists, Tried adding SG manually as well as using [PBI Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.workspaces/add-powerbiworkspaceuser?view=powerbi-ps) but no luck.
Any leads are highly appreciated..

[image]

Comment: Try again, and try with a new SG.  AAD is a globally-distributed application and changes take some time to propagate throughout the system.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, any idea how long does it take usually to propagate in  throughout the system ? I had tried after 1 hour of removing all members but no luck :(

Comment: FYI, total number of members in SG were around ~15K.. as multiple SG's were a part of this super SG am trying to add.

Comment: It's more like 10min.  1 hour should rule that out.

Comment: Ok, it seems going by new SG the only option left for me. Will try & update.

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with @*David Browne - Microsoft*, try creating a new SG to resolve the issue.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I created a new Azure Security Group:

[image]

Now, by using the below **PowerShell script** I added the SG as the viewer:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

$Body = @{
identifier = "SGObjectID"
groupUserAccessRight= "Viewer"
principalType= "Group"
}
$BodyJson=$Body | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Method Post -Url "groups/7af52c7e-fe65-4bd5-b879-414c0bxxx/users" -Body $BodyJson
```

[image]

After executing the script, the **SG is added successfully as a viewer in the Power BI portal** like below:

[image]